# Single function for iterating over dictionaries with keys having a different number of elements

Tags: python

First of all, I apologize ahead of time if the terminology of my question is wrong.  There's probably a better name for what I'm calling a "single-element key" and a "multiple-element key" for a dictionary.  (python newbie warning)

If my code has one dictionary with a single-element key and another with a multiple-element key, how would one function iterate through both dictionaries?

Example - how to write a single function that prints the following dictionaries of lists:

`d1 = { "a": [ 12, 435, 3453, 12, 22 ] , "b": [ 33, 44, 23, 2 ] , "c": [ 3, 43, 12, 4, 125, 3321 ] }`

`d2 = { ( "a" , 100 ) : [ 21, 345, 53, 21, 22 ] , ( "b" , 200 ): [ 3, 3344, 32, 289 ] , ( "c" , 100 ): [ 3, 234, 21, 1214, 12, 31 ] , ( "a" , 300 ): [ 321 ] }`

Here's sample code that fails when printing d2 using the function print_hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

d1 = { "a": [ 12, 435, 3453, 12, 22 ] , "b": [ 33, 44, 23, 2 ] , "c": [ 3, 43, 12, 4, 125, 3321 ] } 
d2 = { ( "a" , 100 ) : [ 21, 345, 53, 21, 22 ] , ( "b" , 200 ): [ 3, 3344, 32, 289 ] , ( "c" , 100 ): [ 3, 234, 21, 1214, 12, 31 ] , ( "a" , 300 ): [ 321 ] } 

def print_hash( h , desc ):
   "display a hash's keys and each key's values"
   print( '----- start: ' + desc )
   for key , values in h.items():  # works for single-element key, fails for multiple-element key
      print( 'key: %s' % key )
      for v in values:
         print( '\t%s' % v ) 
   print( '----- end: ' + desc )

print( '----- start: d1' )
for key , values in d1.items():
   print( 'key: %s' % key ) # example of how to print a hash with a single-element key
   for v in values:
      print( '\t%s' % v ) 
print( '----- end: d1' )

print( '----- start: d2' )
for ( keya , keyb ) , values in d2.items():
   print( 'key: %s / %s' % ( keya , keyb ) )  # example of how to print a hash with a multiple-element key
   for v in values:
      print( '\t%s' % v ) 
print( '----- end: d2' )

print_hash( d1 , 'd1' ) # works

print_hash( d2 , 'd2' ) # fails with "print( 'key: %s' % key ) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
```

print_hash could be modified to print d2, but then it wouldn't print d1.
I'd like to know how to rewrite print_hash so it doesn't fail for either dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to simplify your code and achieve what you want; f-string handles both cases (string or tuple) properly:

```py
d1 = { "a": [ 12, 435, 3453, 12, 22 ] , "b": [ 33, 44, 23, 2 ] , "c": [ 3, 43, 12, 4, 125, 3321 ] } 
d2 = { ( "a" , 100 ) : [ 21, 345, 53, 21, 22 ] , ( "b" , 200 ): [ 3, 3344, 32, 289 ] , ( "c" , 100 ): [ 3, 234, 21, 1214, 12, 31 ] , ( "a" , 300 ): [ 321 ] } 

def print_hash(h, desc):
    print('---- start:', desc)
    for k, values in h.items():
        print(f"key: {k}")
        for v in values:
            print(f"\t{v}")
    print('---- end:', desc)

print_hash(d1, 'd1')
print_hash(d2, 'd2')
```

Output:

```py
---- start: d1
key: a
        12
        435
        3453
        12
        22
key: b
        33
        44
        23
        2
key: c
        3
        43
        12
        4
        125
        3321
---- end: d1
---- start: d2
key: ('a', 100)
        21
        345
        53
        21
        22
key: ('b', 200)
        3
        3344
        32
        289
key: ('c', 100)
        3
        234
        21
        1214
        12
        31
key: ('a', 300)
        321
---- end: d2
```